# Grouping array based on values

Tags: php, arrays

I want to group array values 
my array looks like below with 30 mins time interval

```
$arr = ["00:00","00:30","01:00","01:30","02:00","02:30","03:00","04:30","05:00","05:30"];
```

i want the output like

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 00:00 [1] => 03:00 ),[1]=> Array ( [0] => 04:30 [1] => 05:30 )) ;
```

Here is my code for achieving the result

```
$output = array();
$start = $arr[0];
for($i=1; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    if($i == count($arr)-1) {
        $interval = array($start,$arr[$i]);
        array_push($output,$interval);
        break;
    }
    if((int)($arr[$i]) - (int)($arr[$i-1]) > 1) {
        $interval = array($start,$arr[$i-1]);
        array_push($output,$interval);
        $start = $arr[$i];
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

but i got the result looks like

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 00:00 [1] => 05:30 ) )
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to group with 3 hours interval?

Comment: no Abbas . i want to group array values with start and end time with 30 min interval , if any time is grater than 30 minutes interval it will treated as new array .

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$times = ["00:00","00:30","01:00","01:30","02:00","02:30","03:00","04:30","05:00","05:30"];

$result = array();

$index = 0;
for ($i=0; $i < count($times); $i++){
    if($i == 0){
        $result[$index][] = $times[$i];
    }elseif($i == count($times)-1){
        $result[$index][] = $times[$i];
    }else{
        if((h2m($times[$i])-h2m($times[$i-1])) > 30){
            $result[$index][] = $times[$i-1];
            $index++;
            $result[$index][] = $times[$i];
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);


FUNCTION h2m($hours) {
    $t = EXPLODE(":", $hours);
    $h = $t[0];
    IF (ISSET($t[1])) {
        $m = $t[1];
    } ELSE {
        $m = "00";
    }
    $mm = ($h * 60) + $t[1];
    RETURN $mm;
}
```